# How to move the median point with the character for Mixamo animation ? (GIFs included to explain)

Tags: animation, parent

I learned how to use Mixamo animation but I faced a problem which is for some animation, the median point (im not sure if that is the correct name) doesn't move with the character which creates many problems for me as I want to combine multiple animation in one timeline.

To explain what I mean, here is an example, I parented a cube to my character so when I move the character the cube (with the character's median point) move with it.

[image]

However, when I add this animation and play it, the cube (with the median point) *does not* move with the character

[image]

Comment: The armature does not move when the animation is played. Only the poses move. I don't know what you want to do with the cube, but you should parent it to a bone to make it move with the character.

Comment: thank you for your replay, actually i parented the cube with the bones to show that for this specific animation, nothing moves with the character, not the cube nor anything parented to it, that's the whole point of parenting the cube.

Comment: The gif are very low resolution, so hard to see. But it seems that the cube is parented to the whole armature (dot line pointing to the armature origin), not to a bone.

Comment: yep that's my point, how to change the position of armature origin with time?